# Finding and updating XML node in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the following XML node in my XML document that I need to update:

```
<ImageUrl>xxx.xxx.com/imageeditor/X.jpg</ImageUrl>
```

With the following:

```
<ImageUrl>xxx.xxx.com/image/getdvimage/X/1/false/200/200/</ImageUrl>
```

where "X" in the first string is a number (9808 for example) and needs to be in the place of "X" in the second node.  This is the only node called ImageUrl in the document, and I need to update the whole document this way. So I need help finding the X in the node and replacing it with the X in the updated node and saving the file.

I am trying this code:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'D:\temp\feed.xml'
Foreach ($item in (Select-XML -Xml $xml -XPath '//ImageUrl'))
{
    $oldValue = $item.node.innertext #need to get the value from the last "/" to the .jpg value 
    $newValue = [string]::Format('xxx.xxx.com/image/getdvimage/{0}/1/false/200/200/',$oldValue) #place the $oldValue into the new string here

    $item.node.Name = ???
}
$NewPath = 'D:\temp\FeedUpd.xml'
$xml.Save($NewPath)
```

Here is the XML I am using:

```
 <Product>
            <ExternalId>2127</ExternalId>
            <Name>test</Name>
                                <Description>
                <![CDATA[
               desc
                ]]></Description>
            <BrandExternalId>xxx</BrandExternalId>
            <CategoryExternalId>Foo</CategoryExternalId>
                                <ProductPageUrl><![CDATA[xxx.com/2127]]></ProductPageUrl>
                <ImageUrl>xxx.com/imageeditor/2127.jpg</ImageUrl>
            <ModelNumbers>
                <ModelNumber>2127</ModelNumber>
            </ModelNumbers>
            <ManufacturerPartNumbers>
                <ManufacturerPartNumber>2127</ManufacturerPartNumber>
            </ManufacturerPartNumbers>
            <UPCs>
                <UPC>841101002711</UPC>
            </UPCs>
        </Product>
```

If I could pull the Model Number to insert into the new string `{0}` I wouldn't have to parse the old ImageUrl, just insert the Model into the string.  How would I grab the `<ExternalId>` and the `<ImageUrl>` in the loop to replace?

Comment: Foreach ($item in (Select-XML -Xml $xml -XPath '//ImageUrl'))
{
    $item.node.Name = ???
}
$NewPath = 'D:\temp\FeedUpd.xml'
$xml.Save($NewPath)

Running this code, it will not find the ImageUrl tag for me to even get the text from to try and do a replace.

Comment: Stepping through the code above, it doesn't step into the Foreach loop and $item never has a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact requirements for updating the `<ImageUrl>` elements are unclear, but here's something that demonstrates all the techniques needed (PSv4+, due the use of the `.ForEach()` collection operator):

```
$inFile = 'D:\temp\feed.xml'
$outFile = 'D:\temp\feed-updated.xml'

# Read the input file into an in-memory XML document (object model).
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content -Raw $inFile)

# Loop over all <Product> elements (anywhere in the document)
# Note: Since we already have an in-memory XML document, using method
#       .SelectNodes() is more efficient than using the Select-Xml cmdlet.
#       Similarly, the use of collection operator .ForEach() is more efficient
#       than use of the ForEach-Object cmdlet.
$xml.SelectNodes('//Product').ForEach({

  # $_ is the <Product> element at hand, and its child elements
  # can simply be accessed with *dot notation*.

  # Get the model number...
  $modelNo = $_.ModelNumbers.ModelNumber

  # ... and use it to update the <ImageUrl> child element
  $_.ImageUrl = 'xxx.xxx.com/image/getdvimage/{0}/1/false/200/200/' -f $modelNo

})

# Save the modified in-memory XML document back to disk.
# Note: 
#   * Creates a file with BOM-less UTF-8 encoding.
#   * Be sure to use an *absolute* file path, because the .NET framework's
#     current directory typically differs from PowerShell's.
$xml.Save($outFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this done, so I just created a console application in c# that pull in the data and parsed it quickly for me. I used the XDocument and SelectNodes to pull in the data

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"d:\temp\xxx.xml");
        XmlNode docElement = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNamespaceManager nsman = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsman.AddNamespace("ns", docElement.NamespaceURI);

        foreach (XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("//ns:Product", nsman))
        {
            string prodID = null;
            string ImageUrl = null;
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in row.ChildNodes)
            {
               //Process the node data here
            }
        }
        doc.Save(@"d:\temp\xxx.xml");
```

Processed my 530 rows in less than a second.